# Nagios disk check for windows server using hard values and not percentages

Tags: nagios

I'm using nsclient++ to check our windows server and so far so good. However, for servers with large disks, the 10% threshold isn't cutting it. Ten percent is really 18G free and that's still a lot of available space. Is there a way to specify a hard value say "6G" instead of 10%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a fixed size in nsclient++ CheckDriveSize command, see http://nsclient.org/nscp/wiki/CheckDriveSize .  That said, NTFS suffers from performance problems on partitions that are greater than 80% full so just keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can always change the percentage.  Some of our larger systems are tuned to alert at, e.g., 5% or 2%, depending on (a) total available space and (b) usage patterns.

Answer (score 0):

As larsks said we also just adjust the percentage to fit the needs of the server.  Although it's worth considering that if you're down to 10% on a drive, that means you've got it 90% full - you still might want to consider cleaning it or adding more storage.  While 18 gigs free is a lot - you still may want to have ample time and warning to start considering what, if any, actions you may need to take soon.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in mind that filesystems do start to have performance issues as they fill up.  XFS is probably the most notorious for this.  So while 20% may seem high it is possible for it to cause some issues.

Also most ext* filesystems default to 5% reserved space.  So it's possible to run into out of space issues before you actually fill up the drives.

Answer (score 0):

FIY.

In 0.3.9 (not yet release BTW) "check_mk's magick" disk modifiers will be added so it can rescale the percentages between large and small drives (so you can use 80% but for very large drives this will be increased to a larger value).

// Michael Medin